# Как вызвать метод главной страницы из контекста приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Разрабатываю универсальное приложение.

Требуется после вызова PickSaveFileAndContinue в событии Activated приложения вызвать метод принадлежащий MainPage.

В MainPage метод Save():

```
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
....
savePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue();
```

После выбора места сохранения попадаем в OnActivated класса App:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
if (continuationEventArgs != null)
{
switch (continuationEventArgs.Kind)
{
case ActivationKind.PickSaveFileContinuation:
    FileSavePickerContinuationEventArgs arg2 = continuationEventArgs as FileSavePickerContinuationEventArgs;
    ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ВЫЗВАТЬ МЕТОД ИЗ MainPage;
    break;
}
}
#endif
```

Однако конструкций типа App.Current.MainWindow нет, как обратиться к MainPage?

Comment: Для начала, логика программы должна быть не в классах представления. А в рамках классов view model'и как из одного класса вызвать метод другого, думаю, сложности не составляет.